# Switching <td> backgroundcolor and fontcolor at the same time

Tags: javascript

I have a simple table here where I can switch the background color when clicked.

The below code switches the background color back and forth when clicked. I need also the font color to be switched in the same manner when clicked (in addition to background color switching). The default font color is white, when clicked, it would be black, and at second click, it would be white again. 
The code is like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var all = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    all[i].onclick = inputClickHandler;
  }
};

function inputClickHandler(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var tdElm = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (tdElm.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(154, 201, 157)') {
    tdElm.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  } else {
    tdElm.style.backgroundColor = '#9ac99d';
  }

}
```

```css
.rep {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 45px;
}

.rep td {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
}
```

```html
<table class="rep">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why not just define the colours in a class and then add and remove the class - would be a lot easier to code and maintain too

Comment: @Pete is correct, of course, but if for whatever reason you don't want to do that, you could just set the `tdElm.style.color` immediately after setting the `backgroundColor`.  (Meanwhile: The question is tagged with jQuery but the javascript shown is vanilla, and there's no particular reason to convert it to (or describe it as) jQuery.)

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery?!

Comment: I dont get it, why you are not using toggleClass instead of bunch of code? And I dont see any jQuery in your code btw.

Comment: No, I am not able to use jQuery.

Comment: Why the hell is it tagged then? xD

Comment: I've removed the jQuery tag.

Comment: Mhm I noticed...

Comment: I thought it was jQuery. I didn't do it wrong intentionally.

Comment: No no it's fine but now I put up a solution for jQuery xD

Comment: There you go... now color switch with jQuery, JavaScript, and my prefered solution ;) xD

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback.

Comment: @Jason... just a question back to you... why does the accepted answer (which may be correct) now use jQuery? ;D

Comment: I'm sorry, i guess I should've written javascript instead of jquery.  I assumed it's jquery. It's my negligence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```js
$(function(){
  $("td").click(function(){
    if($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(154, 201, 157)'){
      $(this).css('background-color', '#fff')
      $(this).css('color', 'white')
    }else{
      $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(154, 201, 157)')
      $(this).css('color', 'black')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.rep {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color:whitesmoke;
  border-collapse:collapse; 
  width: 10%;
  margin: 10px; 
  float: left;
  margin-left:45px; 
} 
.rep td {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  height:17px;
  width:17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="rep">
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

**JavaScript:**

```
if(variable) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = "firstBGColor";
  element.style.color = "firstFGColor";
} else {
  element.style.backgroundColor = "secondBGColor";
  element.style.color = "secondFGColor";
}
variable = !variable
```

**jQuery:**
`$("body").css("background-color", "blue").css("color", "white")` This jQuery code changes the background color and the color of the body "at the same time".

**Prefered:**
But I would suggest creating classes and settings and removing them. It makes the code way more maintainable.

```
if(variable) {
  element.className = "firstClass";
} else {
  element.className = "secondClass";
}
variable = !variable

**CSS**
.firstClass {
  background-color: firstBGColor;
  color: firstFGColor
}
.secondClass {
  background-color: secondBGColor;
  color: secondFGColor
}
```